# stopping javascript action on a link inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs with onclick actions associated with them. Inside each div there is a normal link. When i click the link, the javascript is executed (which is fast) and THEN the new page associated with the link starts to load (a fraction of a second later).

What can i do to the link to make it not execute the javascript - although it is located inside the div defined in the script? Is there a way of excluding it from the association, or telling it to stop all javascript onclick?

Thanks!

Comment: If you didn't have the `onclick` handler in the first place, it wouldn't execute JavaScript ... what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could stop the event propagation for the link inside your `div` elements, like so

```
$('div a').on('click', function(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation()
   /* do something */ 
});
```

doing so, when you click on a link, the handler associated to the `click` event for `div` elements won't be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ,

```
   $("#yourlinkId").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the onclick handler of the link return false, e.g. like this:

```
<a href="http://foo/bar" onclick="return false">
```

Or, in jQuery notation:

```
$('div a').on('click', function(e) { return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could prevent the default action by

```
$('div a').on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

i think stop propogation would prevent any further events that are caused by clicking the link where as prevent default will just stop the actual link click?